# all $A_i$ are connected sets such that $\bigcap\limits_{i\in E} A_i \neq \emptyset$ then $\bigcup\limits_{i \in E} A_i$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

This is my proof

---

Suppose not.
Then, $\cup A_i$ has an open partition $\{U,V\}$

$U \subseteq \cup A_i$ so we only need to show two cases:

1. $U \subseteq \cup A_j$ with $U \neq \cup A_j$ for some $J \subseteq E$. Then there exists some $A_k$ such that $U \neq A_k$ with $U \cap A_k \neq \emptyset$. Thus $\{ U \cap A_k,V \cap A_k \}$ is an open partition of $A_k$. By assumption, $A_k$ is connected. It's a contradiction with [$\cup A_i$ is disconnected]
2. $U= \cup A_t$ for some $T \subseteq E$. Since $V \neq \emptyset$, there exists some $A_k$ such that $(A_k-U) \neq \emptyset$. Let $J=T \cup \{k\}$. Then by Case 1, It's a contradiction with [$\cup A_i$ is disconnected]

---

Is it okay??
I'm not sure about this...

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that I don’t understand in your proof. In particular:

1. $U \neq \bigcup_j A_j$ : on what set is the union performed?
2. Same things for case 2. with $T$.

I would just say as $$\bigcap_{j \in J} A_j$$ is supposed to be non empty, let’s take $x \in \bigcap_{j \in J} A_j$.

As by hypothesis $$\bigcup_{j \in J} A_j \subseteq U \cap V,$$ we can suppose without loss of generality than $x \in U$ (we can swap the role of $U,V$ in the other case).

Now for any $j \in J$, $A_j$ is supposed to be connected and $x \in A_j$. Therefore $A_ j \subseteq U$ and finally $$\bigcup_{j \in J} A_j \subseteq U$$ proving that the union is connected.